# Eigenvalues of Hermitian Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a given hermitian matrix

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda & e^i \\
e^{-i} & \lambda \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

wherein $\lambda$ is a real number, through the properties of a hermitian matrix its eigenvalues must be a real number, and since the only real numbers in this matrix is $\lambda$, is it safe to assume that the eigenvalues of this matrix is $\lambda$ without calculating for it?

Comment: There is no reason to think the eigenvalues of a matrix will be foound among the entries of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it's not and you gave already the explanation.... just calculate the eigenvalues of your matrix... they are $\lambda \pm 1$ therefor not $\lambda$